# Apply style to multiple elements not working

Tags: html, css

If I hover over `.iconName` the `svg` and `h1` should change color.

But the `h1` is changing color even without hovering.

The multiple elements work in the first lines but in the hover style it's not working correctly as you can see in the code snippet.

```css
html, body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

svg, h1 {
    color: red;
}


.iconName {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.iconName:hover > svg, h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconName">
  <svg width="48" height="48"><path fill="currentColor" d="M5.35 37.25v-4.6H42.7v4.6Zm0-11V21.7H42.7v4.55Zm0-10.95v-4.6H42.7v4.6Z"></path></svg>
  <h1>Menu</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: it has to be `.iconName:hover > svg, .iconName:hover h1 { ... }`. Alternativly you can use SASS: `.iconName:hover > { svg, h1 { ... } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have done it right.. just a small fix needed

```css
html, body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

svg, h1 {
    color: red;
}


.iconName {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.iconName:hover > svg,.iconName:hover >  h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconName">
  <svg width="48" height="48"><path fill="currentColor" d="M5.35 37.25v-4.6H42.7v4.6Zm0-11V21.7H42.7v4.55Zm0-10.95v-4.6H42.7v4.6Z"></path></svg>
  <h1>Menu</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: i think its already answered below

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select all the child inside a div, you can try this also

```
.iconName:hover > *{
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Please add some documentation from a website like MDN (Mozilla Web Docs).

Answer (score 0):

Just to mark this as an answer:

In order to change the colour on both `svg` and `h1` elements your CSS should be like this:

```css
html, body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

svg, h1 {
    color: red;
}


.iconName {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Update this */
.iconName:hover svg, 
.iconName:hover h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="iconName">
  <svg width="48" height="48"><path fill="currentColor" d="M5.35 37.25v-4.6H42.7v4.6Zm0-11V21.7H42.7v4.55Zm0-10.95v-4.6H42.7v4.6Z"></path></svg>
  <h1>Menu</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding a snippet doesn't make it more of an answer as before. Good that you can copy a comment. To bad, you didn't realized it was made as a comment because this is ultimately a typo/syntax error

Comment: Make an answer to make the question answered doesn't seem to be a bad idea ([What if I answer a question in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment))
It just would have been good to explain the changes, and mention the comment that answered like "as @tacoshy mentionned in comment, [...]".